# $f(x) \geq 0$ is log-convex and $f'(x)<0$. For any integer $k$, does the $k$'th derivative ever change sign?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f(x)\geq 0 $, $f'(x)<0$, with $f(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$.

Furthermore assume $f''(x)f(x)\geq (f'(x))^2$. The last condition is simply log-convexity. Can we say anything about whether, the $k$'th derivative, $\frac{d^k \, f(x)}{d x^k}$ changes sign?

Here is what I've done: If the condition for log-convexity held with equality, after rearranging the terms we get $f''(x)=\frac{(f'(x))^2}{f(x)}$. Differentiating both sides leads to
$f'''(x)= \frac{(f'(x))^3}{f(x)^2}$, which is clearly always negative. In fact, the $k$'th derivative will be $f^{(k)}=\frac{(f'(x))^k}{f(x)^{k-1}}$; thus, no derivative changes sign. The sign is completely driven by whether $k$ is even or odd.

My question then is, is this true when log-convexity holds with a strict inequality?

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer below, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Log-convexity means $l(x):=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln f(x)$ of a function $f$ is convex, or that
$$f(x)=e^{g(x)}$$
for some convex function $g$.

When $l(x)=0,\,\forall x\ge0$, we have $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

For strict inequality, there are functions the odd $k$'th derivative of which change signs. Consider
$$f(x)=e^{x^2-x}.$$

Consider general $g$. For $k=2$,
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=e^{g(x)}(g''(x)+g'(x)^2)\ge0, \quad\forall x.$$

Let us see how to generate sign switching for even $k\ge 4$. For example,
$$
\frac{d^4}{dx^4}e^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)} \big(g^{(4)}(x) + 3 g''(x)^2 + g'(x)^4 + 4 g^{(3)}(x) g'(x) + 6 g'(x)^2 g''(x)\big).$$
To obtain a sign change, $g^{(4)}(0)$ can be made negative with a large magnitude and $g^{(3)}(0)$ made non-negative then both decay monotonically and swiftly towards $0$. This makes the above expression negative in $[0,x_1)$ then positive in $(x_1,\infty)$ for some positive $x_1$.